# How can I use VMware on a Windows Server 2016 VPS?

Tags: vmware-workstation, hyper-v, vps, windows-server-2016

If I try to do that, I get:

"
VMware Workstation and Hyper-V are not compatible. Remove the Hyper-V role from the system before running VMware Workstation.
"

I tried lots of tutorials... none work.
for example:

---

from https://communities.vmware.com/message/2720129#2720129

If I try

```
      bcdedit /set hypevisorlaunchtype off
```

it doesn't work

If I try

```
     Dism /online /disable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

it runs successfully, but VMware still doesn't work

---

from https://communities.vmware.com/thread/565353

If I try

```
     bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

it runs, but VMware doesn't work.

---

I followed the steps here: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2146361
but that is for Windows 10, and it doesn't work 
(The first step is applicable, but the rest aren't at all)

Comment: If you're on a VPS, you're already running on a VM - and nested VMs may need specific settings on the host side.

Comment: how do I get it to work?

Comment: I think the starting point is what VM your host runs - and you'd need specific settings on the *host*

Comment: I think my VPS uses Openstack, and i particularly want to use Vmware. Is it even possible?

Comment: (My VPS instance is Windows Server 2016)